# Валидация модели с помощью атрибутов DataType(DataType.Url) vs UrlAttribute в asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Для валидации модели в ASP.NET MVC 5 есть атрибут [DataType] и в соответствующем перечислении DataType.Url. Но также присутствует атрибут [Url]. В чём разница, если таковая вообще есть?
Пример модели:

```
    public class Article
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public short Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ЧПУ")]
    [StringLength(400)]
    [DataType(DataType.Url)]
    [Url]
    public string URL { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заглянув в исходники asp.net mvc обнаружил, что разницы практически никакой нет. UrlAttribute унаследован от DataType.Url, и в свою очередь проходит дополнительную проверку через регулярное выражение. Видимо новый атрибут [URL] был введён для упрощения, а также для обновления шаблона регулярного выражения для проверки URL-адреса на более новый, полный и законченный.
Вывод: можете смело использовать новые атрибуты типа [URL], [EmailAddress] и т.п для валидации модели вместо старого атрибута [DataType] и соответствующего перечисления.